# how to sort date strings in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How to get the first key after a certain date?

What is the best solution when date_table is getting larger?

```
def get_first():
    date_table = {
        'this is example 1': '01:20 2013-08-07',
        'this is example 2': '11:45 2012-03-23',
        'this is example 3': '19:00 2013-12-01', 
    }
    certain_date = '12:14 2013-06-23'
    # TODO: sort, filter

print get_first()
>> 'this is example 1'
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to sort then filter, as well as parse all the dates in your structure:

```
from datetime import datetime

certain_date = datetime.strptime(certain_date, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d')
match = next((k for v, k in sorted((datetime.strptime(v, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d'), k) for k, v in date_table.iteritems()) if v >= certain_date), None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> certain_date = datetime.strptime(certain_date, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d')
>>> next((k for v, k in sorted((datetime.strptime(v, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d'), k) for k, v in date_table.iteritems()) if v >= certain_date), None)
'this is example 1'
```

The alternative is to filter all dates that come after and is closest to your search date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

parse = lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d')
certain_date = parse(certain_date)
match = min(date_table, key=lambda k: parse(date_table[k]) - certain_date if parse(date_table[k]) > certain_date else timedelta.max)
```

Demo:

```
>>> min(date_table, key=lambda k: parse(date_table[k]) - certain_date if parse(date_table[k]) > certain_date else timedelta.max)
'this is example 1'
```

You really want to rethink your structure, and use something like a heap queue or btree to keep your data structure more accessible for this kind of access.

Even a sorted list with parsed `(datetime, key)` tuples  would perform *much* better, as the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) would let you find your 'next' value in O(log n) time as opposed to O(n log n) for sorting or O(n) for the complex `min()` filter.

You can quickly turn your structure into such a list with:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Entry(object):
    def __init__(dt, key):
        self.dt = dt
        self.key = key

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return self.dt == other.dt and self.key == other.key

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        if self.dt < other.dt:
            return True
        return self.dt == other.dt and  self.key < other.key

date_list = [Entry(datetime.strptime(v, '%H:%M %Y-%m-%d'), k) for v, k in date_table.iteritems()]
date_list.sort()
```

then find your next match with:

```
import bisect
match = date_list[bisect.bisect(date_list, Entry(current_date, None))]
```

and you use `bisect.insort()` to keep the list sorted.

Comment: being a .net guy i was looking around and i'm surprised python doesn't have a built in bst...unless im missing something, just a personal observation btw..nothing to do with your answer :)

Comment: I've found that binary search trees always need that extra tweak that is hard to capture in a library. They are dead easy to write yourself.

Comment: binary search trees themselves are easy, but they're not good, they need to be balanced that could be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best solution when date_table is getting larger?

Dictionaries are not well suited for range retrieval (that is when you want to retrieve a range of values based on their keys). This is because dictionaries use hashing to store keys and therefore cannot guarantee sort order, however for this trade-off they do provide constant time look ups for any particular key.

For range retrievals your best bet is to use some form of a balanced binary search tree, i'm sure there are plenty of implementations for Python if you google for one. These allow you to perform range retrieval at logarithmic time, which is obviously slower than constant, but definitely faster than linear.

That being said, if you absolutely know that your dictionary will not grow past a certain small size, then it is perfectly acceptable to use linear search on keys, because the difference in performance will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module and `min` here:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> certain_date = '12:14 2013-06-23'
>>> c_d = datetime.strptime(certain_date, "%H:%M %Y-%m-%d")
>>> def func(x):
        d =  datetime.strptime(x[1], "%H:%M %Y-%m-%d")
        delta =  d - c_d if d > c_d else timedelta.max
        return delta
... 
>>> min(date_table.items(), key = func)
('this is example 1', '01:20 2013-08-07')
>>> min(date_table.items(), key = func)[0]
'this is example 1'
```

`datetime.strptime` converts the date to a datetime object, so `c_d` now looks something like this :

```
>>> c_d
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 23, 12, 14)
```

Now inside `func`:

```
delta =  d - c_d if d > c_d else timedelta.max
```

This checks whether the current item's date is newer than `c_d` or not, if yes then it returns their difference else it return `timedelta.max`.

Where `timedelta.max` is :

```
>>> timedelta.max
datetime.timedelta(999999999, 86399, 999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might even be able to get away without converting your strings to `datetime` objects, here's an option using `bisect`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from bisect import bisect

name, tds = zip(*sorted(( (k, v.split()[::-1]) for k, v in date_table.iteritems()), key=itemgetter(1)))
certain_date = '12:14 2013-06-23'.split()[::-1]
print name[bisect(tds, certain_date)]
# this is example 1
```